# SQL Delete statement slow execution

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

Below SQL query is taking more than 2 mins. Please suggest some alternative.

```
DELETE from Table1
WHERE (a, b, c, d) IN (SELECT a, b, c, d
                       FROM Table2
                       WHERE a = 1 AND p_date BETWEEN '17-NOV-2014' AND '22-JAN-2208')
  AND a = 1
```

**Explain Plain**:

```
|   3 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE |              |  2232K|    76M|       |  2273   (2)| 00:00:28 |     1 |     1 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL    | Table2       |  2232K|    76M|       |  2273   (2)| 00:00:28 |     1 |     1 |
|   5 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL    |              |   283M|    28G|       |   328K  (2)| 01:07:20 |     1 |   104 |
|   6 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE |              |   283M|    28G|       |   328K  (2)| 01:07:20 |KEY(AP)|KEY(AP)|
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL    | Table1       |   283M|    28G|       |   328K  (2)| 01:07:20 |   KEY |   KEY |
```

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

```
   1 - access("a"="a" AND "b"="b" AND "c"="c" AND 
              "d"="d")
   4 - filter("p_date">=TO_DATE(' 2014-11-17 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
              "p_date"<=TO_DATE(' 2208-01-22 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Comment: I wonder why I cannot edit your question. To format code or tables, you can select all and press ctrl+k. please do it.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Though it will possibly not speed it up: You don't need the `and a = 1` in the outer where-condition, because you'll only match `a=1` - entries because of your sub-select.

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the (partial) execution plan.

Comment: Your explain plan is incomplete so difficult to interpret the numbers. Are the `283M` and `328K` numbers estimate vs. actual rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a partition in the `Table2`? Also changing the `IN` clause with `EXISTS` **may** make the query run faster in Oracle... Try this and see if there is any difference -

```
DELETE from Table1 x
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1
             FROM Table2 y
            WHERE y.b = x.b AND y.c = x.c AND y.d = x.d AND y.p_date BETWEEN '17-NOV-2014' AND '22-JAN-2208' AND y.a=1)
       AND x.a = 1
```

Comment: Yes, there is a partition on Table2... The query you suggested is taking 47 secs.

Comment: 60% faster! Not bad. Now can you ensure that partition pruning happens on `Table2`? What is the partitioned column? Is it `p_date`? What type of partition is this? Range/List?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of partition pruning. Partitioned column on Table2 is a. And it is List type of partition.

Comment: If it's a list partition on column `a` and we are also using the predicate `a = 1` then I guess database is smart enough to perform partition pruning (i.e. partition selection) if required. ..I don't really see any more improvement possibility there - but my knowledge is very limited :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy to help! Btw, If this solved your problem then please click the tick beside my answer to choose it as answered.